# connection to Azure table storage fails

Tags: .net, azure, web-applications, azure-table-storage

I am working on a new web app and I am trying to connect to an existing Azure table storage.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
public class GetEmailAddressesController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Address()
    {
        string emails = "";

        // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("________"));

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("experimentsEmailAddresses");

        // Construct a table query.
        TableQuery<TableData> query = new TableQuery<TableData>();

        foreach (TableData entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
        {
            emails += entity.Email + ";";

        }

        ViewBag.Message = " " + emails;
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

The code will compile but when I run it on debug mode I get an error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   connectionString'

i.e. my connection string isn't valid, although I copied it from the Access keys in Azure.

What is the best solution for that?

Comment: Where are you storing your connection string within the config file?

Comment: under web.config I added     <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="___" />

Comment: Specifically, it is under appSettings or connectionStrings?

Comment: it is under appSettings

Comment: My other suggestion would be to: 1. Step through and make sure that CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("________")); is returning what you think it is. 2. Take the connection string returned by your app and attempt to connect through Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure why is this not working for you, I can able to work this from my end.If you are still not able to work, you can use the typical way of getting the values `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]`

Comment: I test the code, it worked well.And I also tried to reproduce the error, the error only showed while the string "StorageConnectionString" in app.config  is null or your spelling didn't match the CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("________")) string.So maybe you can check did you configure the app.config correctly.

Comment: You could check the app.config referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet?toc=%2Fzh-cn%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fzh-cn%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#configure-your-storage-connection-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
```

to

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = cloudStorageAccount.Parse("StorageConnectionString");
```

And it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("________"));
```

To:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
```

Hope it helps!